# typescript: how to pick a type in object?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get a type in object which belong to interface

```
interface Action {
 type: string,
 payload: {
    name: string
 }
}
```

In this case I want to pick payload.name type how to do this?

What I tried is `Pick<Action , "payload.name">`, but failed any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
type A = Action["payload"]["name"]  // yield string
```

direct access to the index will give you the  desired type